# Append items to a list automatically every x time

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have to go through an array one by one evry x time and show on a list, so it goes down vertically automatically.

```
<ul class="list-group">
</ul>
```

Problem is all i have is my array of data. How can i iterate through one by one every x time and show on the list?

```
$(function(){
    var data = GetData();
    $('.list-group').append(data);
});
```

Comment: You are searching for [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = ['item1','item2','item3','item4'];
var index = 0;
var myinterval;
$(document).ready(function(){
  myinterval = setInterval(addItem, 1000);
});

function addItem()
{
  $('.list-group').append('<li>'+data[index]+'</li>');
  index++;
   if(index == data.length)
    clearInterval(myinterval);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your data with `forEach` and add each element after an interval:

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5];

const list = document.getElementById("list");
data.forEach((x, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = x;
    list.appendChild(li);
  }, index * 1000);
});
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: this seems to be what i'm looking for althought ill have to modify it to setinterval show only x items on screen.